# Issue(s) with the constructing http POST request

Tags: java, http, rest, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm able to do a POST request in SOAP UI. But I cannot do the same from java, been trying for about 5-6 hours and can't find the wining combination. Here is my xsd schema part for the post I'm trying to make to work :

```
<method name="POST">
<request>
<param name="username" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
<param name="id" style="query" type="xs:long"/>
<representation mediaType="multipart/form-data"/>
</request>
```

I just c/p payload in soap ui :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ImageList xmlns="http://someurl/1.0/image" >
  <Image>
    <Name>sampler.jpg</Name>
    <Filename>C:\\sampler.jpg</Filename>
    <Label>
      <Value>Test image</Value>
    </Label>
    <ImageMetadata>
      <Format>jpg</Format>
      <Height>300</Height>
      <Width>400</Width>
    </ImageMetadata>
  </Image>
</ImageList>
```

Then I add attachment in the attachment tab. `Name`, `Content-Type`, etc and I get valid response code however I don't manage to do the same with java, here is what I got :

```
HttpRequestBase post = new HttpPost();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        post.setURI(new URI(URL));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // set number of retries
    post.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(1, false));
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpPost post = (HttpPost) method;
    try {
    post.setURI(new URI(URL));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileBody uploadFilePart = new FileBody(new File("C:\\sampler.jpg"));
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("upload-file", uploadFilePart);

    //payload
    String requestBody = fileToString("src/main/resources/imageBodyPayload.xml");

    HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    parameters.setLongParameter("id", 951);
    parameters.setParameter("username", "test");

    post.setParams(parameters);
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody, "multipart/form-data", HTTP.UTF_8));
    response = client.execute(post);
```

So I set payload as string to the post request but I cannot add file attachment at the same time.

This is how raw request from soap ui looks like :

```
POST http://localhost:9080/imageUpload/?id=951&userame=test HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="----=_Part_9_23652504.1341953390382"
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Can't replicate the same behaviour

Comment: May be worth tagging with whatever http framework this is?

Answer (score 1):

You are not attaching the `MultipartEntity` to the `HttpPost` request in your example, which is why the file isn't uploading. Maybe try something like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

String requestBody = fileToString("src/main/resources/imageBodyPayload.xml");
reqEntity.addPart("request-body", new StringBody(requestBody));

FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File("C:\\sampler.jpg"));
reqEntity.addPart("upload-file", fileBody);

HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams();
parameters.setLongParameter("id", 951);
parameters.setParameter("username", "test");

httppost.setParams(parameters);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I don't know what the value of "request-body" would be in your case, but each part of a multipart/form-data request needs to have a name, so if you are trying to send a file and some XML in a single request, you need to give both the file part and the XML part names.

> A "multipart/form-data" message contains a series of parts, each representing a successful control.
> Each part is expected to contain a name attribute specifying the control name of the corresponding control.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2